# Unity VideoPlayer, how to show how much of the video has buffered

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple theater in Unity that retrieves long videos from a URL. The built-In video player takes a URL then does a progressive download from that URL. This means the video starts playing as it is being downloaded.

How do I get access to how much data, or how many frames, the video player in unity has downloaded so far? I want to show the user how much the video has buffered in real-time.

I am using the standard VideoPlayer object from UnityEngine.Video.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Aside from checking for `isPrepared`, I don't think that you are able to check for a current buffer. [Source](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html)